# How to test for jQuery Traverse/Selector to Missing DOM element - undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined

I am trying to determine if the results of a jQuery selector (by traversing the DOM) has actually found a DOM element, but I am having some issues. I thought that by checking if the variable was equal to `undefined` or `null` would work in this instance, but it has not for me. I feel like I am missing something basic here. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my example.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/q4jzD/2/)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>

    </li>
</ul>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
var
    $element = $("ul li"),
    $parent = $element.parent().closest("li"),//this is the selector that is giving me the issue
    $r = $("#results")//just used to append the results of the if statement below
    ;

$r.append("<br />$parent = " + $parent);
$r.append("<br />typeof $parent = " + typeof $parent);
$r.append("<br />$parent.length = " + $parent.length);
$r.append("<br />$parent[0] = " + $parent[0] + "<br />");//for Chrome

if ($parent === "null") { $r.append("<br />$parent === 'null'") }//not expected to work, just testing
if ($parent === null) { $r.append("<br />$parent === null") }//not expected to work, just testing
if ($parent == null) { $r.append("<br />$parent == null") }//not expected to work, just testing

if ($parent === "undefined") { $r.append("<br />$parent === 'undefined'") }
if ($parent === undefined) { $r.append("<br />$parent === undefined") }
if ($parent == undefined) { $r.append("<br />$parent == undefined") }

if ($parent[0] === "undefined") { $r.append("<br />$parent[0] === 'undefined'") }
if ($parent[0] === undefined) { $r.append("<br />$parent[0] === undefined") }
if ($parent[0] == undefined) { $r.append("<br />$parent[0] == undefined") }

if (typeof $parent === "undefined") { $r.append("<br />typeof $parent === 'undefined'") }
if (typeof $parent === undefined) { $r.append("<br />typeof $parent === undefined") }
if (typeof $parent == undefined) { $r.append("<br />typeof $parent == undefined") }


if (typeof $parent[0] === "undefined") { $r.append("<br />typeof $parent[0] === 'undefined'") }
if (typeof $parent[0] === undefined) { $r.append("<br />typeof $parent[0] === undefined") }
if (typeof $parent[0] == undefined) { $r.append("<br />typeof $parent[0] == undefined") }

if ($parent.length == 0) { $r.append("<br />$parent.length == 0") }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/q4jzD/2/)

These returned `true`; `$parent[0] === undefined` and `$parent[0] == undefined` and `typeof $parent[0] === 'undefined'`;

This makes sense since the jQuery selector did not find any DOM objects and there is no element `[0]`. I only tried this because of using `console.log` with an object in Chrome needs this. But I do not think that this is correct.

`$parent.length == 0` works as expected. But is this needed with a `!== undefined' and`!== null`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"`$parent.length == 0` works as expected. But is this needed with a `!== undefined` and `!== null`?"* Huh?... No. As you stated, it works. There's your answer.

Comment: `$parent.length == 0` can work fine enough.

Comment: @thesystem, Since `$parent` did not find an element in the DOM, then I expect `$parent.length` to equal 0. Right? What I am trying to determine is if `$parent` is `undefined`, then should I first check to see if `$parent` is not null and not undefined?

Comment: @pktangyue, then why when I check for `$parent == undefined` it does nto work?

Comment: @JoeFletch: A jQuery DOM selection will never return `undefined` or `null`. It will always return a jQuery object.

Comment: I missed the point that a jQuery selector will *always* return an object. So I was missing something basic here. Thanks for the responses and explanations. Sorry I missed that point initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the selector or traversal results in zero matching elements, the `length` property of the jQuery object will be equal to `0`. The standard - and only necessary - method of checking if elements matched is:

```
jQueryObject.length === 0
```

All jQuery functions that select elements will themselves return a jQuery object (which contains the matching elements), so it's impossible for the result of that to ever be `null` or `undefined`. It will always return an object, and that object will always have a `length` property.

Looking at your specific example:

```
var $element = $("ul li"),
    $parent = $element.parent().closest("li")
```

If there are no `<li>` elements inside `<ul>` elements when that code executes, `$element` will be an empty jQuery object (a jQuery object with a `length` property equal to `0`). Calling `$element.parent()` will in turn return an empty jQuery object, and then calling `.closest('li')` will also return an empty jQuery object.

Now, assuming there are `<li>` elements inside `<ul>` elements when the code executes; in this case, `$element` will be a non-empty jQuery object. They'll all have a parent, so calling `$parent` will return a jQuery object that contains some elements. If, however, none of those elements have a `<li>` element between them and the document, then `.closest('li')` will return an empty jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the results of a jQuery selector always being an object.

Comment: @JoeFletch No problem, it's not necessarily intuitive. Though almost all jQuery functions themselves returning a jQuery object (with the same, or a different, set of elements) is the reason that chaining jQuery functions is possible.